# Jquery kill un-needed timeouts

Tags: jquery, timeout

**So I have 2 buttons.**

Button a: is a button. **(#button1)**

Button b: fake submit button. **(#right_r)**

Button c: submit button. **(#right)**

By default, button A will show, and will preventDefault() on click and show an error message.

*When I click on button A, it will set a timeout 8000, so in 8 seconds, it will replace button B with button C.*

**But the problem is:**

When user clicks on the button A multiple times, it sets a lot of timeouts.

**What I want to do is, kill the previous timeout before setting a new one, `like stop it.`**

**My code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#right_r").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#error").slideDown("slow");

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#error").slideUp("slow");    
        }, 1000);
    });
    $("#button1").click(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#right_r").hide();
            $("#right").show();
        }, 8000);
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var right_r_timeout = null, runelocus_timeout = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#right_r").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#error").slideDown("slow");

        if (right_r_timeout != null) {
            clearTimeout(right_r_timeout);
            right_r_timeout = null;
        }
        right_r_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#error").slideUp("slow");
        }, 1000);
    });

    $("#runelocus").click(function() {
        if (runelocus_timeout == null) {
            clearTimeout(runelocus_timeout);
            runelocus_timeout = null;
        }
        runelocus_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#right_r").hide();
            $("#right").show();
            runelocus_timeout = null;
        }, 8000);
    });
});
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: It didn't work, I think because javascript is overwriting variable right_r_timeout.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the built-in delay method, this would be easy..

```
$("#error").stop(true,true).slideDown("slow").delay(1000).slideUp("slow")
```

Note however `.delay()` only delays animation methods and `.queue`'d methods.

Comment: Yes but, error will work, but the new button will appear right away, I want it to reset the timeout on click, so it will take it another 8 seconds to show button C